# How to find a function that fits a given set of data points in Julia?

Tags: function, mapping, julia

So, I have a vector that corresponds to a given feature (same dimensionality). Is there a package in Julia that would provide a mathematical function that fits these data points, in relation to the original feature? In other words, I have x and y (both vectors) and need to find a decent mapping between the two, even if it's a highly complex one. The output of this process should be a symbolic formula that connects x and y, e.g. (:x)^3 + log(:x) - 4.2454. It's fine if it's just a polynomial approximation.

I imagine this is a walk in the park if you employ Genetic Programming, but I'd rather opt for a simpler (and faster) approach, if it's available. Thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but the "official" name for your problem is **regression** (in case of polynomial relation between x and y this would be polynomial regression). Use this term to continue search for answer.

Comment: I'm familiar with regression. Not interested in minimizing MSE or some other error metric though. Just want to find a function fit, even if there is some overfiting. I don't plan to use this for predictive analytics.

Comment: In this case _Lagrange's interpolation formula_ might help. It produces a polynomial which passes through all points (x,y). The polynomial will have high degree. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: That's very useful. Although this doesn't have a package either, it's fairly easy to implement. Just need to focus on the key data points or do some clever sampling. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the `Polynomials.jl` package includes the function `polyfit` which does Lagrange interpolation. A usage example would go:

```
using Polynomials    # install with Pkg.add("Polynomials")
x = [1,2,3]          # demo x
y = [10,12,4]        # demo y

polyfit(x,y)
```

The last line returns:

```
Poly(-2.0 + 17.0x - 5.0x^2)`
```

which evaluates to the correct values.

The `polyfit` function accepts a maximal degree for the output polynomial, but defaults to using the length of the input vectors `x` and `y` minus 1. This is the same degree as the polynomial from the Lagrange formula, and since polynomials of such degree agree on the inputs only if they are identical (this is a basic theorem) - it can be certain this is the same Lagrange polynomial and in fact the only one of such a degree to have this property.

Thanks to the developers of `Polynomial.jl` for leaving me just to google my way to an Answer.

Comment: That's great. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to MARS regression. Multi adaptive regression splines.

Comment: Thanks. This looks interesting. However, it's not implemented yet, so I'll go with another alternative.